# Python: Using Hachoir, how extract metadata for file-like objects?

Tags: python, stream, metadata, hachoir-parser

I'm working on a site that users uploads videos and audio files, I when uploaded, some common metadata fields must be populated from the file. I have found [Hachoir](https://bitbucket.org/haypo/hachoir/wiki/Home) and it seems good, but with a problem, to create a parser for metadata reading, what is required is a filename, rather than a file-like or stream object.

How to use Hachoir with file like objects?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using Hachoir v3.2.1:

```
import hachoir.metadata
import hachoir.parser
import hachoir.stream

parser = hachoir.parser.guessParser(hachoir.stream.InputIOStream(file_handle, None, tags=[]))
if parser:
    hachoir_metadata = hachoir.metadata.extractMetadata(parser)
    if hachoir_metadata:
        metadata: Dict[str, str] = hachoir_metadata.exportDictionary()['Metadata']
        print(metadata)
```